# I am getting ' [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.' error in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, desktop, flutter-getx

I am getting  ' [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.'  error in flutter. I'm using getx.

> [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
> You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
> If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
> or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
> (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
> If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.

My code is :

```
        RxList<String> selectedBanks = <String>[].obs;
        RxList<String> banksSHTextList = <String>[].obs;
           Obx(
               ()=> DropDownMultiSelect(
                      onChanged: (List<String> x) {
                         RxList<String> rxList = x.obs;
                         _dbsController.selectedBanks = rxList;
                      },
                      isDense: false,
                      options: _dbsController.banksSHTextList,
                      selectedValues: _dbsController.selectedBanks,
                      whenEmpty: 'Seçiniz',
                    ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use `Obx` widget, you have to use `Rx` variable widget which depend any variable.

Solution

```
RxList<String> selectedBanks = <String>[].obs;
RxList<String> banksSHTextList = <String>[].obs;
Obx(()=>   DropDownMultiSelect(
              onChanged: (List<String> x) {
                
                 _dbsController.selectedBanks =x.obs;
              },
              isDense: false,
              options: _dbsController.banksSHTextList.value,
              selectedValues: _dbsController.selectedBanks.value,
              whenEmpty: 'Seçiniz',
            ),)
```

Comment: I need to wrap it with obx.

Comment: No, you needn't or you are  doing something wrong

Comment: The data there comes when another button is pressed. I need to wrap it with Obx so it can be updated.

Comment: I just realized the error. Thank you.